# Laravel + Vue.js application routing not working properly

Tags: laravel, vue.js

Laravel + Vue.js application  routing  not working  properly.
when i run laravel + vuejs application   "http://127.0.0.1:8000/user"  everything is working fine  but when i run my application on xampp server using this url "http://localhost/Ecommerce/" then  vue-router not working.
For example   when i click on my navigation link "users" then it will redirect to 
"http://localhost/user" instead of "http://localhost/Ecommerce/user"   .
Please help.

Comment: Please show us what your routes in both Laravel and vue-router are.

Comment: web.php  



Route::get('/', function () {
    return view('welcome');
});

Auth::routes();                                                                        

Route::get('/home', 'HomeController@index')->name('home');

Route::get('{path}',"HomeController@index")->where( 'path', '([A-z\d-\/_.]+)?' );

Comment: and app.js is

require('./bootstrap');
window.Vue = require('vue');
import VueRouter from 'vue-router'

Vue.use(VueRouter)

const routes = [
    { path: '/dashboard', component:require('./components/Dashboard.vue') },
    { path: '/user', component: require('./components/User.vue') }
  ]

Vue.component('example-component', require('./components/ExampleComponent.vue'));

const router = new VueRouter({
    mode: 'history',
    routes // short for `routes: routes`
  })

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router
});

Comment: thanks for reply @Delena Malan

Comment: if i am using  Ip address    instead  of  domain name  its working fine.

Answer (score 5):

Try adding a `base` url when you create you VueRouter, e.g.

```
new VueRouter({
    base: '/Ecommerce/', 
    routes: [...],
});
```